# Laravel 5.1 - redirect->intended() returns "The HTTP status code "1" is not valid."

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-5.1

I'm attempting to implement the `redirect()->intended()` method in my login function to bring the now-logged in user back where he came from, but I always get this error:

> InvalidArgumentException in Response.php line 470:  The HTTP status
>   code "1" is not valid.`

```
public function processLogin($region, $lang)
{
  if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $_POST['email'], 'password' => $_POST['password'], 'active' => 1])) {
        return redirect()->intended('index', array('region' => 'ca', 'lang' => 'fr')); // line that messes up
    }
  return redirect()->route('login', array('region' => 'ca', 'lang' => 'fr'))->withErrors('invalid login');
}
```

When I change the `intended(...)` to `route(...)`, it works fine but it always redirects to the index route.

Am I missing anything?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Remember that `intended()` only works if you come from a `GET` request

Comment: That's what I thought as well. I made sure that the login dropdown form was being filled on a `GET` route, and that didn't work either.

But now that you mention it, the processLogin function is a `POST` request... does that change anything?

Answer (score 0):

try this. Redirect `HTTP code 1` is not allowing you to take another parameter along with it. Redirect means that you are sending the request to show that particular page there is a difference between view and redirect.

I hope this helps ... :)

```
if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $_POST['email'], 'password' => $_POST['password'], 'active' => 1])) {
    return redirect('index');
}
```